# Difference between serverless.EmptyServerless template and serverless.AspNetCoreWebApp dotnet core Amazon Lambda Templates

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have been testing out the dotnet Amazon Lambda templates installed using:

```
dotnet new -i Amazon.Lambda.Templates::*
```

Assuming that all three of these solutions are completely serverless:

serverless.AspNetCoreWebApp - Lambda ASP.NET Core Web Application with Razor Pages
serverless.AspNetCoreWebAPI - Lambda ASP.NET Core Web API
serverless.DynamoDBBlogAPI - Lambda DynamoDB Blog API

I deployed the DynamoDBBlogAPI as a test using the cloud formation template and it appears to be based off of the standard serverless.EmptyServerless template. Multiple lambda functions in a single Function.cs file. In the AWS console I see several lambda functions were created w/ each one corresponding to a function in Functions.cs:

Function to get a list of blogs
Function to add a blog
Function to get a single blog
Function to remove a blog

I am trying to figure out the difference  between this setup and how an entire AspNetCoreAPI application can be serverless as well. Does the API gateway aspect go away? I am assuming that now it points to a single lambda which runs an entire AspNetCoreWebAPI project and the project handles it from there, rather than having a bunch of separate Lambda functions handling things.